# ¿Por qué no se abre el segundo JOptionPane?

Tags: java

En el siguiente código, al compilarlo y ejecutarlo, no me aparece el segundo JOptionPane.

¿Sabéis por qué puede ser?

Gracias. Un saludo.

```
package com.mycompany.prueba001_ventanas;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author davidpozocatalina
 */
public class PruebaVentanas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int resultado;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola Mundo");
        
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(s.next(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número: ")));
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El número introducido es: " + num1);
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt(s.next(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número: ")));
```

ese scanner se queda esperando por algo que no va a llegar y el JOptionPane ocupa su lugar sin ningún problema. De hecho, es extraño que lo uses, si con parsear lo que retorne el JOptionPane basta

Usar una versión más simple

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt((JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número: ")));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El número introducido es: " + num1);
```

Hace lo que esperas.